# Angular - Pull Down Form - Values not taken into account

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, forms

Here is there my source code for a pull down angular form :

```
<form (submit) = "save()">
<div>
<label for="status">User Status </label>
<select>
<option type="text"  name="status" [(ngModel)]="user.status" 
value="approved">Simple User</option>
<option type="text"  name="status" [(ngModel)]="user.status" 
value="disapproved">Professional</option>
<option type="text"  name="status" [(ngModel)]="user.status" 
value="other">Other</option>
</select>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

The form is executed properly and the data are saved in the database but the value for the field "status" remains empty (and not "approved", "disapproved" or "other" as wished). Would you know how to fix that please ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like this.

And `[(ngModel)]` should be on `<select>` tag not on `<option>` tag.

And `user.status` should have value **approved**, **disapproved** or **other**.

```
<form (submit) = "save()">
  <div>
    <label for="status">User Status </label>
    <select [(ngModel)]="user.status" name="status">
      <option value="">Not Selected (Empty)</option>
      <option value="approved">Simple User</option>
      <option value="approved">Simple User</option>
      <option value="disapproved">Professional</option>
      <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

---

**Update :**

`name` attribute is used for angular validation, `[(ngModel)]` for binding,

if you are not going to validate with angular you don’t have to use `name`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but I tried and it doesn't work : I have a mongo DB and a new document is added but the corresponding field "status" is still an empty field of type "text". Do you think it can come from another problem ?

Comment: Yes, make sure user.status has value "approved", "disapproved" or "other". Or else you can check by adding  empty `<option>` like in my updated answer. Now if user.status is empty it will show "Not selected"

Comment: Your advice was a good one in order to prevent other possible bugs. However it was enough to fix my problem but I found the solution. : I forgot to put an attribute "name" into <select>. I'm going to write my final solution in the next answer.

Comment: You directly copied my answer friend, You could have just edited my answer with just  `name="status"` and accept it.